# Open web page at a specific time of day; or after 8 hours of activity

Tags: windows, windows-7, google-chrome, automation

I'd like my browser (or OS) to automatically open up a traffic report web page just before I go home from work--ideally after 8 hours of being logged in at work, but a specific time of day would work too.

What's the best way to do this?  I use Windows 7 and prefer Google Chrome.

Comment: Are you trying to get it to work using task scheduler or do you want an alternative method? This is in response to your comment, which has now been deleted.

Comment: yassarikhan786, Task Scheduler is fine.  I was hoping, however, for a solution that can detect how long I've been at work instead--which I am guessing Task Scheduler can't do.

Comment: Yeh, as far as I know Task Scheduler doesn't have that functionality.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Going off your original comment, you can achieve the above using `Task Scheduler.`

On Task Scheduler, right-click on the `Task Scheduler Library` and choose `Create Basic Task`

- The first step is pretty trivial - Give your task a name and description.

  [image: Task Scheduler Step 1]
- You want it to run daily, so you don't need to do anything for the next step.

  [image: Task Scheduler Step 2]
- On the next step choose a starting date and time and how often you want the task to repeat.
- On the `Action` stage of the Wizard select the `Start a program` option. This is where you will need to specify the location of the application `(Google Chrome)` you want to execute and any additional parameters. Specify the website you want to open in the `Add arguments` section. As an example I've used `http://www.bbc.co.uk/news`

  [image: Task Scheduler Final Step]

Once that is done, click `Next` and then `Finish`. Google Chrome should now open at the specified time every day and it should load the website listed in the Add arguments section.

**Additional Notes:** If you can't find where Google Chrome is located, right-click and go into its properties. On the `Shortcut` tab, the `Target` field is what you need.

---

## From the comment by @TravisHeeter

You can also use a "Weekly" trigger to have the task run on week days:

[image]

Also, for any scheduled task to work, you may have to restart your computer. You can test your task after it's created:

Make sure it's selected in the middle column, then click "Run":

[image]

If nothing happens, your task didn't work, and a restart should be considered.

Comment: I'd like to add that if you choose "Weekly" instead of "Daily" you can choose which days it runs on. This allows you to only run it on work days if you wanted. Also, you may have to restart your computer before it will work. You can test it by doing this: Once it's created, make sure it's selected in the middle column of the Task Scheduler window, and click "Run" in the Right Sidebar. If nothing happens it didn't work.

Comment: Hey @Yass (Broad City reference?) I went ahead and added some screenshots. Thanks for adding my points.

Comment: Yass is my name shortened :). Short for Yassar.

Comment: Is there a way to perhaps open a site in whatever the user's default browser is? I feel like that should be possible.

Answer (score 2):

While I appreciate the original answer, I have since found the "Tab Snooze" and "Cron Tabs" extensions useful.  The former is what I currently use, as it has a "periodically" feature to have a website open up every weekday.

Answer (score 1):

There is also an online tool for that: https://simpletol.com/openwebsite/

This tool will open any URL you specify at any date and time you specify.

It even shows a countdown to when your page will be automatically opened.

There is no charge to use this tool.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. You should provide at least a link, some additional information about the software itself, and how it can be used to solve the problem in the question.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1230487)